# The notion of conflicting objective functions in multi-objective optimization

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization, non-convex-optimization

In a paper by Carlos A. Coello titled

**A Comprehensive Survey of Evolutionary-Based
Multiobjective Optimization Techniques**

he states:

"Multiobjective optimization (also called multicriteria optimization, multiperformance or vector optimization) can be defined as the problem of finding [65]:
a vector of decision variables which satisfies constraints and optimizes a
vector function whose elements represent the objective functions. These
functions form a mathematical description of performance criteria which
are usually in conflict with each other. Hence, the term "optimize" means finding such a solution which would give the values of all the objective
functions acceptable to the designer."

Also, in another book **THEORY OF
MULTIOBJECTIVE
OPTIM IZATION** by NAKAYAMA, the author states:

"Let us consider the case in
which there are a finite number of objective functions each of which is to be
minimized. If there exists a feasible solution, action, or alternative that
minimizes all of the objective functions simultaneously, we will have no
objection to adopting it as the optimal solution. However, we can rarely
expect the existence of such an optimal solution, since the objectives usually
conflict with one another. The objectives, therefore, must be traded off"

My question is if one wants to define the notion of a "conflict" mathematically would that work: two functions are said to be in conflict if there doesn't exist a feasible solution that "optimizes- individually (in the usual sense of single-objective optimization)" each objective function. Is this valid?

Comment: You wouldn't be able to define "conflict" in terms of the objective functions only, because it also depends on the feasible regions, e.g., the constraints. One could come up with examples of two objective functions that are "in conflict" by your definition under one set of constraints but not "in conflict" under another set.